# pitfalls in builder inside singleton method controller?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, controller, singleton

Lets say I have controller RequestController in Spring which is marked as Singleton. Inside this controller there is a builder which is injected using dependency injection. The main goal for this class is to receive requests and build responses.

```
@Singleton
class RequestController {
    private ResponseBuilder responseBuilder;

    private RequestController(ResponseBuilder responseBuilder){
        this.responseBuilder=responseBuilder;
    }

    public Response getResponse(Request request) {
        return responseBuilder.getRequest(request).build();
    }
}
```

My question:

What kind of pitfalls does this code hide? What could go wrong when we try to use it in normal spring application. @Singleton is only an information that this class will be created only once per applications. 
I know that builder should be thread-safe since it will be responsible for handling multiple requests. But is anything else dangerous here?

Comment: I put an answer. WDYT about my conception?

Answer (score 0):

Before going into your question there's one thing to be mentioned. You have declared your class `RequestController` as **Singleton** with `@Singleton`. If your class is a singleton you should make sure it is immutable, so no state change after creation. So I assume it is a stateless class. So you don't need to have a private constructor, which looks rather messy. Instead you can use,

```
@Inject
private RequestController(ResponseBuilder responseBuilder){
        this.responseBuilder=responseBuilder;
}
```

Please note that, if you maintain a a good design, `ResponseBuilder` class should be an inject-able one. And `RequestController` class should be called only by injection.

Back to your problem, I think you have almost no problem. We should be very careful about `what our real problem is?` rather than `what patterns we could drag and drop into our code?`

Making a Controller, a Singleton is pretty much fine. But I don't find any need to use [Builder](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) pattern to your `ResponseBuilder` (you can change the name also). If your classes are rather simple and have just limited number of operations (a sign of a good design), you would never need builder pattern for your lifetime. It's more like we try to tear the paper with an axe. Why don't you use bare hands?

We should only use **Builder** in situations where we have to make considerably large scope class for some reason. You can have a good example of the use of Builder pattern in [Hamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest). It's an [assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_assertion) tool for Java testing developed by Google. They have used builder pattern for some classes just to make life easier for the programmer who uses that by providing multiple list of tasks out of a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for a reply...I have an idea what it can be wrong with this code...Of course I should use injection on ResponseBuilder. But classically builder pattern have a state so in stateless controller we're using statefull class provided by ResponseBuilder. So automatically builder if it's not thread safe it can cause concurrency problems (race condition). Whenever multiple threads try to get access to builder fields they can get different state (because builder is not thread safe). So when we try to make builder thread safe it will work but a new problem will arise. Since our builder become thread safe only one thread will be able to use it and this can lead us to bootleneck for requests (multiple requests/threads use our method but they will be blocked by builder which is thread safe). Gimme a shout if my thinking is good :)

Comment: I don't get your point, 'builder is not thread safe'. Can you give me a real world scenario?? :))